# Any Excel function that will reverse a string?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, string, string-manipulation

Are there any built-in Excel functions that will reverse a string?

Comment: you should pick the answer with strReverse

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no built-in function that I know of, but you can create your own custom function.

First - create a new module:

1. Get into VBA (Press Alt+F11)
2. Insert a new module (Insert > Module)

Second - paste the following function in your new module ([Reference](http://forums.techarena.in/windows-software/1193083.htm#post4450245)):

```
Function Reverse(Text As String) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim StrNew As String
    Dim strOld As String
    strOld = Trim(Text)
    For i = 1 To Len(strOld)
      StrNew = Mid(strOld, i, 1) & StrNew
    Next i
    Reverse = StrNew
End Function
```

Now you should be able to use the **Reverse** function in your spreadsheet

Answer (score 68):

The [current accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/121632/129719) is a poor way to reverse a string, especially when there is one built into VBA, use the following code instead (should act the same but run a LOT faster):

```
Function Reverse(str As String) As String
    Reverse = StrReverse(Trim(str))
End Function
```

Comment: @n00b - "how to create a module" wasn't the question. :)  This solution is much more efficient/faster/easier, although I'm not sure why `TRIM` was added, since extra whitespace wasnt't specified in the question.  For "huge" datasets, remove `TRIM` if you don't need it.

Answer (score 4):

I found an alternative that doesn't require VBA at https://exceljet.net/formula/reverse-text-string

The formula is

```
=TEXTJOIN("",1,MID(B5,ABS(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(B5)))-(LEN(B5)+1)),1))
```

where B5 is the input cell.

Comment: For me, this only returns the last character.

Comment: Works if entered using **Ctrl + Shift + Enter**

Comment: Works for me in Office 365.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this LET formula:

```
=LET( string, D6,
       L, LEN( string ),
       CONCAT( MID( string, SEQUENCE( 1, L, L, -1), 1) ) )
```

It breaks up the string into an array of 1-character cells and then recombines them back into a concatenated string in reverse order.